# Attempting to utilize a drop down menu in a form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First off, I'm pretty new to Ruby and Ruby on rails, so bear with me.

I'm attempting to have my categories section of my form utilize my category table in my db so that when the author wants to select on a category, they can just select the drop down menu and choose one. For now, I've hard coded them and this works

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>


    <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :author_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.select (:title), [['Finance'], ['Marketing'], ['Programming'], ['Leisure'], ['Management'], ['Food']] %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

but, by switching the categories section to

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all %>
  </div>
```

it will give me a drop down box containing each hash, and I'm not to sure why, but I can't do Category.all.name to get the names (I'm assuming it is because it's in a hash). Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: "I'm assuming it is because it's in a hash". **No it is not a hash**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you need to change you select use `options_for_select` tag:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }), :include_blank => true %>
```

if you want to pre-populate category_id

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ]}, @article.category_id), :include_blank => true %>
```

For more information [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!
It worked, I just have to see why it worked now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the Category model in your Controller? The form can/will only know what the controller knows. It cannot know any more. If this form is attached to the articles_controller then it will have access to @article, but it won't have access to @category.

So this leaves you with a couple options. Define category somewhere in your controller, OR alternatively (and this would be my suggestion) setup some type of association for your Articles model.

Does Article have many Categories? This is a great opportunity to setup that `has_many` association, and then you can access the category model via Article's associations methods.

This is my suspicion, but we really don't have enough information here. Can you post your controller, and your article model so we can see everything that is going on? Also, what error do you get specifically?

Comment: I did define the Category model, defined it as a instance as well as @catergory = Category.all

Comment: Can you post your controller? Did you add the category model in the same method that this form exists in? What error are you getting?